# javascript/angularjs: when opening the modal i do not get the desired data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am updating a SPA but i have a problem i want to display the name of the classes but nothing appears 
here  is the code where i have a problem with maybe i am missing something:

```
    $scope.open = function (classes) {
    $log.info("classes",classes);
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'classes.html',
        controller: 'ModalClassesInstanceCtrl',
        resolve: {
        info: function () {
            var info = {};              
            info['name']= classes.name;
            $log.warn("classes info",info);
            return info;
            }
    }
});
```

what i got in console

```
    $log.info("classes",classes);
```

show that i have 5 classes like this

classes [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

if i click on any object it shows all the data about that object including the class name for example clicking the first object will show the following data

```
    1: Object $$hashKey: "object:13" id: 4 level: "4" name: "fox" year: "2015/2016"
```

but

```
  $log.info("classes info",info);
```

only show class info Object {name: undefined}

please can u check weather i have something wrong in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at this line:
`info['name']= classes.name;`. `classes` is an array of objects, not an object with `name` property - that's why you get undefined. If you want to display a class name, you need to refer to an object inside an array, e.g. `classes[0].name`. If you want to display all classes' names, you should iterate over them and join the names into one string.